.NET 9 Open API endpoint throws exception: "the node must be of type 'JsonValue'"
I'm trying to migrate from SwaggerGen to .NET 9 Open API. First, I had this issue which was resolved by removing all of double.MaxValue use cases in my model validations.
Now navigating to (in my case) /openapi/dev.json throws

InvalidOperationException: The node must be of type 'JsonValue'

I have so many view models and form models and query models in the project and the exception does not give me any clue on where the problem is.

Update (reproducible codes):
After so many commenting and uncommenting lines, I was able to find the problem and the following program can reproduce the exception:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddOpenApi();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapOpenApi();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.MapPost("/add", ([FromBody] MyModel model) => "Done!");

app.Run();

class MyModel
{
    [Length(0, 10)]
    public IEnumerable<string>? SomeOptionalArray { get; set; }
}

I only managed to solve it by removing the [Length] validation.
Note: I discovered this by commenting all endpoints and uncommenting them one by one. So, it's possible other validation attributes would result in this exception. Apparently the new OpenAPI library is not validation friendly.

Can you please provide a [mre]?
